# Is this kind of clamp on a braided PVC hose reusable or does it get replaced with a new one when it is removed?

Tags: hose, terminology

I don't have much experience with PVC hose clamps and have never seen the kind in the photos here. I've only seen the kind with the turn-screw that tightens or loosens the clamp. This one looks like it requires a special crimping tool. To remove it, is it simply pried apart with a flat-head screwdriver?

[image: hose clamp]
[image: hose clamp]

Comment: That clamp cannot be reused.  But I think you can replace it with an ordinary reusable hose clamp.  It would help if you tell us what this is.  What is it clamped to and where does it go?

Comment: It is the water feed hose for a masonry saw. There are two hoses, a larger diameter one that attaches to the water supply (such as a garden hose) and this smaller one (10mm OD) which runs from a stop-valve to a port near the blade.

Comment: Ya you can definitely replace it with a normal hose clamp.  In fact if the hose fits snugly that's probably adequate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the single use kind and are replaced with the screw clamps.

I do not know if a screwdriver will be enough to remove it. Maybe add snips/pliers to add twisting/cutting or a nice angle grinder.